# Calling repaint of an inner class does not trigger paint() actually does nothing

Tags: java, swing, repaint, japplet

I'm not too familiar with JApplet 
and paint and repaint(). Any help is appreciated.

I have an outside class "A" that extends JApplet and draws somestuff in its paint()
I also have a private class "B" that sits inside A and also extends JApplet and draws 
stuff in its paint().
A's paint() evokes B's paint() so when A is ran both A an B are drawn.

I use a mouselistener to detect when a mouse is clicked and that's when
B should repaint() and draw some new stuff and remove older stuff.

When I press my mouse, however, I see that B's repaint() does nothing.
I print a couple debug messages to the console and I can tell 
that when B's repaint() is called nothing happens, i.e., the program should go through
B's paint() again but it doesn't.

Here is the general structure, and again, any help is appreciated

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

    public class A extends JApplet {

        private class B extends JApplet implements  MouseListener{

            public B() { }
            public void paint (Graphics g) {
                // g.drawline ...
                //System.out...
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                //System.out....
                repaint();
            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                //System.out....
                repaint();

            }
            // ... rest of mouse listener interface

        }

        public void init() {
            // setSize() ...
        }


        public  void paint(Graphics g) {
            // g.drawRectange ...
            // Draw other stuff

            B b = new B();
            B.paint(g)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `private class B extends JApplet implements  MouseListener{ public B() { }` (but add `implements  MouseListener` to the outer applet) & it should work as expected (AFAIU). Which leads to the question.. ***Why*** are you trying to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others which shows that your debug `System.out.println()` calls are printed, but the content is not reloaded. Also include the code which shows/loads your applet.

Comment: @Progman *"include a MCVE"* Great idea, and a tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewThompson Didn't know, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that nothing is reacting to the `repaint()` request in your `B` class. It might trigger a repaint of the `B` class but that doesn't mean that the `A` class gets repainted, nobody told him. Like as you said:

> A's paint() evokes B's paint() so when A is ran both A an B are drawn.

That's right, but it doesn't mean it's the same the other way around.

When you want that the `A` class should repaint it's content you have to call `repaint()` on the `A` object, since that's the class you want to be repainted.

Comment: Hi thank you very much but that's not what I asked for. I'm saying that B's repaint should trigger B's paint but it doesn't. I'm not trying to repaint A at all.

Comment: @seansontag How do you display the JApplet `B`?

Comment: I guess I should clarify, to display the JApplet, A's paint() is called once but that's it. After that B should be the one to keep repainting itself.

Comment: @seansontag The problem is that you are displaying the applet `A`, not `B`. Maybe what you are looking for is a normal JPanel added to the layout manager of your JApplet `A`. Please edit your question with the MCVE.